# Generating pdf reports containing text and chart based data

Tags: asp.net, components, charts, reporting

I have to generate downloadable good looking pdf reports containing text and **chart** based data for a commercial application. I found out itextsharp library ( http://itextsharp.com/ ) but it isn't as powerful as I expect.

What components do you use for this kind of requirements? The price is important for me too. I'd be grateful for your advices.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com) or alternatively [Tallcomponents](http://www.tallcomponents.com/). Not sure if they support generating charts out of the box, but for that you could other libraries like [DotNetCharting](http://www.dotnetcharting.com/) or [XtraCharts](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/).

Comment: Perhaps have a look at components which can create a PDF from Silverlight, e.g.: http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/ or http://silverpdf.codeplex.com/ and from that PDF create a PDF which mixes the Silverlight PDF with the html PDF (both components I mentioned before should be able to create a single PDF from multiple sources).

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok to look for commercial solutions for PDF then I would suggest PageFlex. It is very powerful. Check that if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [ActivePdf](http://www.activepdf.com/products/serverproducts/server/index.cfm) in the past to generate reports which contained all types of charts and data. Basically it takes an html page and converts it to PDF so we just had to develop HTML versions of the reports and then if the user wanted a pdf version we just had to create a PDF from the html version of the report. The ActivePdf server had its quirks but it did solve the problem quite well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @lfoust. It just works with html? I'm asking because I have Silverlight graphs in aspx pages. Is it useful for me again?

Comment: It definitely works with aspx pages but I am not sure about the silverlight part. We had some flash based charts that we would just render as .png when the report was in pdf mode.

Comment: Did you not have any issues with charts & graphs not rendering properly? and delays etc with the charts drawing?

Answer (score 0):

[DocRaptor.com](http://docraptor.com) is a great tool for generating pdfs from HTML. It uses Prince XML, and that quality is hard to beat.